# JavaScript, как сделать "фильтр" при клике?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, можете, подсказать по JavaScript. Есть многоуровневое меню, и вот в данной ситуации, по клику на кнопку – `span` с классом `submenu-caret`, у меня открываются и закрываются абсолютно все подменю с классом `shop-menu-level-2`

Как сделать, чтобы функция `slideDown()` и `slideUp()` работала только для того блока с классом `shop-menu-level-2`, который находится в том же родителе, что и кнопка `submenu-caret`, по которой делается клик?

```
    // shop-menu
$('.submenu-caret').click(function () {

        if (this.innerText == "+") {
            this.innerText = "-";
            $('.shop-menu-level-2').slideDown();
        } else {
            this.innerText = "+";
            $('.shop-menu-level-2').slideUp();
        }
});


<li class="level-1 parent">
     <div>
         <span class="submenu-caret">+</span>
         <a href="#">Двигатели</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="shop-menu-level-2">
         <li class="level-2">
             <a href="#">Двигатели дизельные</a>
          </li>
          <li class="level-2">
             <a href="#">Двигатели бензиновые</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
</li>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Доходите до родителя $(this).closest('.level-1') - потом вниз .find('.shop-menu-level-2')

```
$('.submenu-caret').click(function () {
  if (this.innerText == "+") {
    this.innerText = "-";
    $(this).closest('.level-1').find('.shop-menu-level-2').slideDown();
  } else {
    this.innerText = "+";
    $(this).closest('.level-1').find('.shop-menu-level-2').slideUp();
  }
});
```

Comment: разница - четыре секунды :)

Comment: ))) не сразу понял о чем вы )))

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.submenu-caret').click(function () {
  if (this.innerText == "+") {
    this.innerText = "-";
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.shop-menu-level-2').slideDown();
  } else {
    this.innerText = "+";
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.shop-menu-level-2').slideUp();
  }
});
```